# Scons recompiles my code

Tags: c++, bison, scons

I'm using scons in my project. The problem is that I have to call scons twice to get the build to a state where scons does not recompile anything. My build sequence is as follows:

1. Call bison to generate .cpp and .hh files to be included in the C++ compilation.
2. Call C++ compiler to compile the C++ into binary.

The issue is that scons calculates the dependencies before running bison, and at that point the automatically generated .hh file does not exist. Next time I run scons it detects a new dependecy to the .hh file and recompiles. How do I tell scons to do the dependency chain after the bison has run and generated the header file?

Here is an example SConscript that demonstrates the problem.

```
Program(target = 'hello', source = 'hello.cpp')    
CXXFile (source='parser.yy', target=['parser.cc'])    
Depends('hello.cpp', 'parser.cc')
```

Here is the the output from running scons with --tree=prune option 1st. time:

## scons --tree=prune

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
bison -o parser.cc parser.yy
g++ -o hello.o -c hello.cpp
g++ -o hello hello.o
+-.
  +-SConstruct
  +-hello
  | +-hello.o
  | | +-hello.cpp
  | | | +-parser.cc
  | | |   +-parser.yy
  | | |   +-/usr/local/bin/bison
  | | +-hello.h
  | | +-/bin/g++
  | +-/bin/g++
  +-[hello.cpp]
  +-hello.h
  +-[hello.o]
  +-[parser.cc]
  +-parser.yy

scons: done building targets.
```

And here is the output from the second run. You can see that scons finds the dependency to the bison-generated .hh files only when running the second time and that's why it recompiles.

```
# scons --tree=prune
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o hello.o -c hello.cpp
+-.
  +-SConstruct
  +-hello
  | +-hello.o
  | | +-hello.cpp
  | | | +-parser.cc
  | | |   +-parser.yy
  | | |   +-/usr/local/bin/bison
  | | +-hello.h
  | | +-parser.hh
  | | +-location.hh
  | | +-stack.hh
  | | +-position.hh
  | | +-/bin/g++
  | +-/bin/g++
  +-[hello.cpp]
  +-hello.h
  +-[hello.o]
  +-location.hh
  +-[parser.cc]
  +-parser.hh
  +-parser.yy
  +-position.hh
  +-stack.hh
scons: done building targets.
```

hello.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "hello.h"
#include "parser.hh"

int main() {
        return 0;
}
```

and hello.h:

```
#define foo 1
```

Here is parser.yy . These 4 files, hello.cpp, hello.h, parser.yy and SConscript should make up a complete a working example demostrating the issue.

```
 {
%}
%start input
%defines
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%locations
%initial-action
{
    @$.begin.filename = @$.end.filename = &driver.streamname;
};
%define api.value.type {double}
%token NUM 
%left '-' '+' 
%left '*' '/' 
%precedence NEG 
%right '^'    
%% 
input:
  %empty
| input line
;
line:
  '\n'
| exp '\n'  { printf ("\t%.10g\n", $1); }
;
exp:
  NUM                { $$ = $1;           }   
;
%%
```

Comment: Try making your target depend on the generated file, `program = Program(...); env.Depends(program, generated_sources);`

Comment: Try running: scons --tree=prune and paste or pastebin the result.  SCons doesn't need the header file to be there to know it will be there.  That's what Emitters are for.  This is a well worn path so likely it's something minor which is making it not work.

Comment: Above I added the output from running scons with --tree=prune option 1st. time and 2nd time. You can see that scons finds the dependency to the bison - generated .hh files only the second time it was run.

Comment: Can you post a verbatim copy of `hello.cpp` too? It's not clear to me how you actually include the generated parser source into your program. Do you try to include `parser.yy` directly, or the header `parser.hh`?

Comment: Added hello.cpp and hello.h code. They are really just a minimal compilable files to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For correctly detecting that your `bison/yacc` call is also creating a header file, SCons needs the "`-d`" command line flag to be set. Then the corresponding Emitter adds the header file to the list of targets automatically, and it gets included as implicit dependency for the source file `hello.cpp` without having to specify an explicit dependency via `Depends()`.
The following `SConstruct` seems to work fine on my side:

```
env = Environment(YACCHXXFILESUFFIX='.hh',
                  YACCFLAGS=['-d'])

env.CXXFile('parser.cc', 'parser.yy')
env.Program('hello', 'hello.cpp')
```

Note how I instantiate a named build environment `env`, such that I can manipulate its settings more easily. The setting of the file suffix is necessary, because the default in SCons is `*.hpp` for whatever reasons.

You can find more info about the environment variables used above in the UserGuide ( http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html ), and there especially in the Appendix A "Construction Variables".

Regarding the additional files `location.hh`, `stack.hh` and `position.hh`, they are not supported in the latest version of SCons' `yacc` Tool. It looks to me as if the more recent versions of `yacc/bison` have added new keywords like `%locations`, which are currently not parsed to emit the correct list of targets. If you want this to be changed, please come to our User mailing list at `scons-users@scons.org` (see also http://scons.org/lists.php ), describe your problem and provide some more info about the syntax of the required keywords. Then we can try to help you, and all other users, out by extending the `yacc` Tool.

Comment: Thanks for the input but it scons still recompiles the C++ file. If you issue 'scons --debug=explain' it tells that it is recompiling because it found new dependencies to location.hh, stack.hh and position.hh

Comment: I don't see these files getting generated in the SConstruct. Where do they come from? Further, they aren't included in your main "hello.cpp" file, so why should SCons add them as implicit dependencies? Your current state of information doesn't really make sense, meaning it appears to be incomplete. Please provide a complete minimal working example (MWE) that demonstrates your actual problem.

Comment: I added a dummy bison file 'parser.yy'. That together with hello.cpp, hello.h and SConscript file should complete a working example that demonstrates the issue.